# Hide Group audience/content visibility in node

Tags: organic-groups

When displaying a node belonging to some OG, the group audience and the group content visibility is displayed at the end of the node just after the content of the node.

Is it possible to disable that ? 
I would avoid code editing if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the OG content type, you will see a field for group audience. You can simply hide it in the Manage Field tab. Or, you could use CSS. In both cases, you are not hacking the core code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess you meant "manage display", right ?

Comment: You have 2 Manage tabs on all content types: Manage Fields and Manage Display. You could remove it off the display yet if you do not need it you should remove it completely in the fields tab. :)

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark the answer as complete. :)

Comment: As Ben asked, the correct answer here is "Manage display", as the admin might want to set group audience, but not show it in the node.